# How do I update values in streamlit on a schedule?

Tags: streamlit

I have a simple streamlit app that is meant to show the latest data. I want it to re-fresh the data every 5 seconds, but right now the only way I found to do that is via a `st.experimental_refresh`; this is the core code:

```py
import streamlit as st
import time 

current_time =  int(time.time())
if 'last_run' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state['last_run'] = current_time


@st.experimental_singleton
def load_data():
    ...
    return data

data = load_data()
        
if current_time > st.session_state['last_run']+5: # check every 5 seconds  
    load_data.clear()  # clear cache
    st.session_state['last_run'] = current_time

st.experimental_rerun()
```

However, the `st.experimental_rerun()` makes the user experience terrible; are there any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `schedule` and `st.empty()`.

Example:

```py
import time
from schedule import every, repeat, run_pending


def load_data():
    ...
    return data


def main():
    data = load_data()
    # Do something with data

with st.empty():
    @repeat(every(5).seconds)
    def refresh_data():
        main()

    while True:
        run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
```